# Printing to File - Java beginner

Tags: java

I cannot figure out why the following simple program doesn't (create) and then write to a file? Can you spot where the problem is?

```
public class RandomSeq
{
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        // command-line argument
        int N = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );

        // generate and print N numbers between 0 and 1
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < N; i++ )
        {
            // System.out.println( Math.random() );
            StdOut.println( Math.random() );
        }
    }
}
```

When I type the following at the Interactions prompt:

> java RandomSeq 5

```
0.9959531649155268
0.5010055704125982
0.4444779637605908
0.4205901267129799
0.09968268057133955
```

I obviously get the correct output, but when I use piping, it doesn't do what (I think) it should do:

```
> java RandomSeq 5 > f1.txt
```

Comment: If I use System.out.println works. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have. It still wouldn't print the randomly-generated numbers to a file...

Comment: Are you looking into the right directory?. Both the StdOut and System.out.println when piped should create the file with the output.

Comment: StdOut is part of the standard library available from princeton univ - http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdOut.java.html

Comment: I have an 'intros' directory and the file directory (folder) - neither contains a file named f1.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" Java way to write to a file is by using a `Writer` class. I denoted a small example below. Alternatively you can change the `PrintStream` that you write to which then sends the output to a file instead of the console (essentially the same as below)

```
PrintWriter out;
File myfile = new File(folder,"output.txt");
myfile.createNewFile();
fos = new FileOutputStream(myfile);
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8")));
out.println("some text to go in the output file");
```

**Edit:** 
On my machine the code works fine using `System.out.println()`. I can only imagine that there might be a problem with the write permissions, else wise maybe `StdOut` object has some bugs...

```
~/scratch $ java RandomSeq 5 > out.txt
~/scratch $ cat out.txt 
0.5674462012296635
0.05189786036638799
0.1290205079541452
0.22015961731674394
0.6503198654182695
~/scratch $
```

Comment: His question was why his program is not creating the file "f1.txt" when piped (java RandomSeq 5 > f1.txt)

Comment: Precisely, That's my question!

Comment: Using `System.out.println()` (instead of `StdOut`) the code above works just fine. See edit

Comment: @PrabhuBeeman he should clarify the title of the question in that case. The question clearly asks for how to write to a file, and that's what I have answered, with a clean example.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with system.out and it works perfectly for me. There might be a possibility of read/Write permissions on your specific folder or directory because of which it is possible that you are unable to create f1.txt. Try to change the folder permissions or user rights if not proper rights are available. Also make sure that you are finding the file exactly at the same location where the program is creating.

Comment: 'System.out.println( Math.random() );' and then you pipe it this way 'java RandomSeq 5 > f1.txt' and the file is created???

Comment: exactly. Your code and execution method is correct. Its generating f1.txt when i execute java RandomSeq 5 > f1.txt with the similar out put as java RandomSeq 5. I didn't find any issue with your code and method of execution. The only thing left might be user permissions because of which your execution method not able to create file.

Comment: posdef: i think you are copying my statement of Rights permissions.